# Create BiConsumer as Field setter without reflection

Tags: java, reflection, methodhandle

I try to get the maximum performance in one of my scripts, without doing a major refactor.

I spotted method that creates a BiConsumer from a Field using reflection.

```
return (c, v) -> {
    try {
        field.set(c, v);
    } catch (final Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not set field: " + field, e);
    }
};
```

Reflection has the reputation of being slow.
So I though I could use the method handles.

```
Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle mh = lookup.unreflectSetter(field);
return (c, v) -> {
    try {
        mh.invoke(c, v);
    } catch (final Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not set field: " + field, e);
    }
};
```

Which is already a tiny bit faster.
However `BiConsumer` is a `FunctionalInterface` which could just be generated somehow.

```
public static <C, V> BiConsumer<C, V> createSetter(final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup,
        final Field field) throws Exception {
    final MethodHandle setter = lookup.unreflectSetter(field);
    final CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
            "accept",
            MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class),
            MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class, Object.class), // signature of method BiConsumer.accept after type erasure
            setter,
            setter.type()); // actual signature of setter
    return (BiConsumer<C, V>) site.getTarget().invokeExact();
}
```

However then I get an Exception which I don't really understand

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Unsupported MethodHandle kind: putField org.sample.dto.TestDTO.name:(String)void
    at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:182)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303)
    at org.sample.bench.MyBenchmark.createSetter(MyBenchmark.java:120)
    at org.sample.bench.MyBenchmark.main(MyBenchmark.java:114)
```

In which way do I have to generate that setter correctly to increase the performance. (without actually adding a setter method)

Comment: Like the exception says; you can't wrap a putField method handle using `LambdaMetafactory`. Your first solution is the best alternative imho.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee are you referring to the reflection way or the plain method handle?

Comment: The plain method handle way, where you wrap it in a lambda expression.

Comment: Did you benchmark this? or you just think it is slow?

Comment: Both the reflection and method handles are insanely fast after a few executions (if you cache them). However MethodHandles are ~15% faster. Thats why I made this little tradeof.  ~1 line of code for 15% performance improvement. If it is executed >>1000 times then it becomes worth it. (Reflection 1, MethodHandle by name 0.9, MethodHandle by Reflection 0.85)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an invoker `MethodHandle`:

```
public static <C, V> BiConsumer<C, V> createSetter(
                     MethodHandles.Lookup lookup, Field field) throws Throwable {
    final MethodHandle setter = lookup.unreflectSetter(field);
    MethodType type = setter.type();
    if(field.getType().isPrimitive())
        type = type.wrap().changeReturnType(void.class);
    final CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
        "accept", MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class, MethodHandle.class),
        type.erase(), MethodHandles.exactInvoker(setter.type()), type);
    return (BiConsumer<C, V>)site.getTarget().invokeExact(setter);
}
```

Since the `LambdaMetafactory` does not allow to generate a function instance for the field method handle, the code above creates a function instance for a method handle equivalent to invoking `invokeExact` on the field accessor method handle.

In the worst case, the generated code would not differ from the code generated for the lambda expression performing a manual invocation of the method handle’s `invoke` method, so the performance would be on par with

```
public static <C, V> BiConsumer<C, V> createSetterU(
                     MethodHandles.Lookup lookup, Field field) throws Throwable {
    MethodHandle setter = lookup.unreflectSetter(field);
    return (c, v) -> {
        try {
            setter.invoke(c, v);
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not set field: " + field, e);
        }
    };
}
```

However, there are some chances that the invoker method handle is slightly more efficient in some scenarios. First, it uses the equivalent to `invokeExact` rather than `invoke`, an option, the generic code can’t use due to type erasure. Second, there might be some internal tweaks when no user code is involved in the code graph.

Comment: When Im Trying to use this sollution I'm having
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.home.ref.App$$Lambda$15/0x0000000800098040 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract accept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V of interface java.util.function.BiConsumer.

Comment: @Kristoff do you use a field with a primitive type?

Comment: yeah, its boolean.

Comment: Yeah issue is gone, but it seems that executing accept method on this references has no effect. Would you mind lookign at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592566/create-biconsumer-from-lambdametafactory

I have more details there

Answer (score 2):

Functionally [`MethodHandleProxies::asInterfaceInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html#asInterfaceInstance(java.lang.Class,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle)) seems like a good fit. Not sure about the performance impact of the method handle proxies though.

Comment: Bad. Read the source, It uses j.l.r.Proxy. Using Lambda is fine here.