# Create BiConsumer from LambdaMetafactory

Tags: java, reflection, method-reference, lambda-metafactory

I'm trying to dynamically create a method reference of type BiConsumer through LambdaMetafactory.
I was trying to apply two approaches found on https://www.cuba-platform.com/blog/think-twice-before-using-reflection/  - createVoidHandlerLambda   and here [Create BiConsumer as Field setter without reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835353/create-biconsumer-as-field-setter-without-reflection) the Holger's answer.

However in both cases I'm having below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.home.ref.App$$Lambda$15/0x0000000800066040 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract accept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V of interface java.util.function.BiConsumer.
    at org.home.ref.App.main(App.java:20)
```

My code is something like this:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        BiConsumer<MyClass, Boolean> setValid = MyClass::setValid;
        setValid.accept(myClass, true);

        BiConsumer<MyClass, Boolean> mappingMethodReferences = createHandlerLambda(MyClass.class);
        mappingMethodReferences.accept(myClass, true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static BiConsumer<MyClass, Boolean> createHandlerLambda(Class<?> classType) throws Throwable {
        Method method = classType.getMethod("setValid", boolean.class);
        MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
        CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller,
                "accept",
                MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class),
                MethodType.methodType(void.class, MyClass.class, boolean.class),
                caller.findVirtual(classType, method.getName(),
                        MethodType.methodType(void.class, method.getParameterTypes()[0])),
                MethodType.methodType(void.class, classType, method.getParameterTypes()[0]));

        MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
        return (BiConsumer<MyClass, Boolean>) factory.invoke();
    }

    public static <C, V> BiConsumer<C, V> createSetter(Class<?> classType) throws Throwable {
        Field field = classType.getDeclaredField("valid");
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        final MethodHandle setter = lookup.unreflectSetter(field);
        final CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
                "accept", MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class, MethodHandle.class),
                setter.type().erase(), MethodHandles.exactInvoker(setter.type()), setter.type());
        return (BiConsumer<C, V>)site.getTarget().invokeExact(setter);
    }

}
```

Where MyClass looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public boolean valid;

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
        System.out.println("Called setValid");
    }
}
```

I will appreciate for help with this one.

EDIT #1.
After consulting @Holger I've modified createSetter method to:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <C, V> BiConsumer<C, V> createSetter(Class<?> classType) throws Throwable {
        Field field = classType.getDeclaredField("valid");
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        final MethodHandle setter = lookup.unreflectSetter(field);
        MethodType type = setter.type();
        if(field.getType().isPrimitive())
            type = type.wrap().changeReturnType(void.class);
        final CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
                "accept", MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class, MethodHandle.class),
                type.erase(), MethodHandles.exactInvoker(setter.type()), type);
        return (BiConsumer<C, V>)site.getTarget().invokeExact(setter);
    }
```

Now this method does not throw the initial Exception althoug it seems that calling accept on this method reference has no effect. I do not see "Called setValid" in logs for this call. Only for MyClass::setValid;

Comment: The code you’ve copied from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50835353/2711488) is specifically for accessing the field directly, i.e. without calling a setter.

Comment: I know, Setter is for createHandlerLambda method.

Basically I found two ways to should do the trick (one from yours question) but I just cannot make them work ;/

For yours approach Im using straight through access to boolean field valid. That's why it is public.

Comment: @Holger, I got it now. Yeah your solution works, Thanks. The value change was not through setter. That is why I did not see that log line. I'm wondering now How to make the other solution work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that your use of `getMethod` and `caller.findVirtual(…)` for the same method is redundant. If your starting point is a `Method`, you may use `unreflect`, e.g.

```
Method method = classType.getMethod("setValid", boolean.class);
MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle target = caller.unreflect(method);
```

This might be useful when you discover methods dynamically and/or are looking for other artifacts like annotations in the process. Otherwise, just getting the `MethodHandle` via `findVirtual` is enough.

Then, you have to understand the three different function types:

- The target method handle has a specific type which is given implicitly when passing the method handle to the factory. In your case, it is `(MyClass,boolean) → void`
- The generic function type associated with the intended result type
  `BiConsumer<MyClass, Boolean>`, which is `(MyClass,Boolean) → void`
- The erased type of the `BiConsumer` interface, which is `(Object,Object) → void`

Only specifying all three types correctly tells the factory that it must implement the method
`void accept(Object,Object)` with code which will cast the first argument to `MyClass` and the second to `Boolean`, followed by unwrapping the second argument to `boolean`, to eventually invoke the target method.

We could specify the types explicitly, but to make the code as reusable as possible, we can call `type()` on the target, followed by using adapter methods.

- `wrap()` will convert all primitive types to their wrapper type. Unfortunately, this also implies converting the return type to `Void`, so we have to set it back to `void` again.
  This gives us the *instantiatedMethodType* parameter. (Compare with [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-))
- `erase()` will convert all reference types to `Object` but leave all primitive types as-is. So applying it to the *instantiatedMethodType*  gives us the erased type.
  It depends on the particular target interface whether this simple transformation is sufficient. For the interfaces in `java.util.function`, it is.

Another point to raise the reusability is to use an actual type parameter for the method receiver class, as we get the class as parameter anyway:

```
public static <T>
       BiConsumer<T, Boolean> createHandlerLambda(Class<T> classType) throws Throwable {

    MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle target = caller.findVirtual(classType, "setValid",
        MethodType.methodType(void.class, boolean.class));
    MethodType instantiated = target.type().wrap().changeReturnType(void.class);

    CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller,
            "accept", MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class),
            instantiated.erase(), target, instantiated);
    return (BiConsumer<T, Boolean>)site.getTarget().invoke();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.