# Transform non-direct MethodHandle to instance of interface

Tags: java, methodhandle

there is a possibility to transform `MethodHandle` to the instance of `LambdaForm` via:
`LambdaMetaFactory.metafactory()` and invoke it via `invokeinterface` call. I know that it is possible to make it for direct `MethodHandle`. Is it possible to do it for non-direct?

Why I want do it? I have a method `m` that makes 6 different calls to different composed methods called via `invokedynamic`. I see that my calls share same `LambdaForm` and it looks like there is a performance degradation.

Comment: Can you expand on your use-case a bit? Are you generating code (e.g. with ASM) to generate `invokedynamic` instructions? `LambdaForms` are initially shared, but as long as you go through an invoker lambda form the lambda form will be customized after 127 invokations.

Comment: I once [wrote something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71224833/lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-classes-dont-work-when-loaded-as-hidden-classe/71249339#71249339) - it uses `MethodHandles.invokeExact` as direct MethodHandle and passes the non-direct MethodHandle as argument to the constructor.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yeah, I did something similar [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708132/2711488)